# MSBuild .target files specification (what kind of XML is this?)

Tags: xml, msbuild

I've been looking at the XML files the MSBuild uses to execute a build process, specifically the .target files.  As of yet, I haven't been able to find a specification for the syntax found in these files.  A few questions:

- Is there a reference for them?  I'm looking mostly at Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
- What does a statement like

  <FrameworkSDKDir Condition="'$(FrameworkSDKDir)' == ''">@(_TargetFrameworkSDKDirectoryItem)</FrameworkSDKDir>

mean?

I roughly understand that $(FrameworkSDKDir) refers to an environment variable, but why is it quoted in single quotes?  For string interpolation purposes?  What does `@(_TargetFrameworkSDKDirectoryItem)` mean?  All of the expressions with `@` seem to have an `_` before the var name in parens.  Is this convention or is there a deeper reason?

Answer (score 1):

This link has been enlightening:

https://www.codementor.io/solutionsjon/quick-intro-to-msbuild-projects-du10802ae

And here's the schema:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dy88c2e.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As for the @ syntax:

Using the notation @(myType) enables a collection of items of type myType to be expanded into a semicolon-delimited list of strings, and passed to a parameter

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164283.aspx